# what is the meaning of 으로 in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

> 아침 저녁**으로** 많은 사람들이 운동을 하거나 산책을 합니다

by what I have learned,으로 has 2 major meanings:

1)indicate the direction of travel

2)indicate the tool,material used

but the 으로 in the sentence seems not fit in both of meaning,I searched for dictionary,but any of definition given seem not fit in the sentence

Answer (score 2):

(으)로 in your example indicates a time of occurrence.  It is one of the less commonly heard usage of (으)로.  There are many such minor usages to all the major postpositional particles.

Compared with the more common time indicator 에, (으)로 has a nuance that 1) the action or event is recurring regularly, or 2) that it marks a certain duration or number of time something has happened so far.

Here are other examples.

- 밤낮으로 했는데도 일이 아직도 많이 남았다. (밤낮으로 = 밤에도 낮에도)
- 우리 강아지는 조석으로 짖어댄다.  (조석으로 = 아침 저녁으로 = 아침에도 저녁에도)
- 다음달로 이 프로젝트를 시작한지 일 년이 된다. (다음달로 = 다음달이면 / 다음달이 오면)
- 이번 우승으로 이 팀은 다섯 번 우승한 게 된다. (이번 우승으로 = 이번 우승에/으승으로 의하여 = with this win)